# Windows 7 User Permissions - External HDD

Tags: windows-7, permissions, external-hard-drive, file-permissions, window

I have a computer (Windows 7) in which a user logs in and is unable to transfer files from one external HDD to another.  THey are also unable to rename said hard drives.  The error is permission denied.  An administrator of the system can perform these actions.  We attempted to add the user to the local administrator group but the problem remained. The temporary solution was to add the user to the `Domain Admins` group to allow them to continue their work.  We also tried turning off all the GPOs being applied to that machine and the permissions error is still present.  **What permission setting is causing this and what is the best way to allow the user to complete these actions?**

One solution that is unacceptable for this enviornment is editing the security of the individual drives.  This requires a "tag" to be added to each file.  There are dozens of HDDs 3TBs in size so this process would be too long and therefore unacceptable.

The other temporary solution of adding the user to Domain Admins is a security concern and only a stop gap.

Comment: At this point I would just create a new domain user, change the exsiting user name something like `original_backup` and disable the account, and name the new user to `original`.  You can then migrate the profile files at your leasure.

Comment: @Ramhound not really sure what you're trying to say here

Answer (score 1):

Create a group that would include those users.

After that, give it permission to external drives.

You can give permission for Domain Users, or at least for the group Authenticated Users.

[image: add group]

way 2, Authenticated Users group, bad security:

[image: Authenticated Users group, bad security]

[image: replace permission]

Comment: Yes, this would indeed work but wouldn't you have to set these permissions for each and every external HDD that is plugged into the PC?  We had considered this solution as well but we would prefer not to create a custom group.  If we were to do so, is there a specific permission set that will allow this action instead of changing the security for all the drives individually? I find it odd users can still create files on these drives but cannot copy files between them or rename the drives themselves...has to be something else going on

Comment: @user2104891 This behavior indicates a problem with the group `Authenticated Users`. For example, this group is blocked or reduced some of its rights to the domain by the GPO. Since all permission to write to disk and renaming gives this group. Not `Doman Users`. Look at the prohibition of cross-checks and other important rights. You perform write files in the directory external drive?